# How do we "unprotect" a protected question?

Tags: discussion, support

In this example

[What is the correct answer to "alles klar"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4591/what-is-the-correct-answer-to-alles-klar)

we overhastily "protected" the question, likely because one of the answers of a new user included a question about his answer being correct or not.

It is my believe that rather than blocking new users from answering by protecting a question we should help them to formulate appropriate answers either by commenting or editing. If an answer is a comment rather than an answer we should flag it for moderator attention to be deleted and transformed into a comment.

Neither a "protection" nor transforming of the answer into a comment was needed in the example above because is could be turned into a valid answer by simply removing the additional question part.

Is there any way to **"unprotect"** a protected question in case we feel that protection was not really justified?

Comment: I disagree with you. I know that you see the "risk" that we lose a potential new user because he isn't able to answer the question and immediately turns around, but I see the whole thing from another point of view. I prefer the way which Hendrik proposed: To ask a new question. So, if I am new, can't answer or comment to a question, then I either wait until I've the privileges or add a new question regarding to a previous question. In that case I choose to protect the question, because that kind of question is very likely to experience unwanted responds by new users and it took only 2 days.

Comment: Moreover, that respond is completely true, but to my mind it's not worth for an answer. I could add thousands of possible replies to such a question, but they are not meaningful. And "Es muss" is such a horrible answer on "Alles klar?", and I hate it everytime when I hear it. Such as "Schlechten Menschen geht es immer gut" as respond on that kind of question. It's not what I want to hear. All these stupids answers give a connotation of "I'm doing like I'm feeling good, but indeed it's not" and provoke either requesting or turning away. So, for me it's just a comment worth.

Comment: The second comment is just a side note on why I hate exceeding answers. That's the reason why I just comment the question, although my comment is quite the same kind of respond as "es muss".

Comment: @Em1: The point is that there wasn't (yet) any _need_ for protecting the question - at least that's what I think. If a 2nd or even 3rd answer of this type comes, _then_ it may be time to protect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only moderators can unprotect questions. Just flag the question and a moderator will review it.

In this case I agree with you and I unprotected the question.